# Plotting a line on a grid layout, then addition veritcal axis

Tags: math, grid, line, plot, pixel

**SOLUTION AT BOTTOM OF THIS QUESTION**

I have this code:

```
public void lineImproved(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, Color color)
{
    int pix = color.getRGB();
    int dx = x1 - x0;
    int dy = y1 - y0;

    raster.setPixel(pix, x0, y0);
    if (Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy)) {          // slope < 1
        float m = (float) dy / (float) dx;      // compute slope
        float b = y0 - m*x0;
        dx = (dx < 0) ? -1 : 1;
        while (x0 != x1) {
            x0 += dx;
            raster.setPixel(pix, x0, Math.round(m*x0 + b));
        }
    } else
    if (dy != 0) {                              // slope >= 1
        float m = (float) dx / (float) dy;      // compute slope
        float b = x0 - m*y0;
        dy = (dy < 0) ? -1 : 1;
        while (y0 != y1) {
            y0 += dy;
            raster.setPixel(pix, Math.round(m*y0 + b), y0);
        }
    }
}
```

It currently plots a line and fills in the specific pixels that make up the line between the 2 points specified (i.e. [x0,y0] and [x1,y1]). I need it to include an h0 and h1 for the height of the 2 points. By doing so I hope to be able to obtain a height value on the vertical axis with every raster.setPixel function.

**UPDATE
I have now the code how it should be for this task, but still only in 2D. I need to implement the suggested solution to the following code to verify it:**

```
    internal static int DrawLine(Player theplayer, Byte drawBlock, int x0, int y0, int z0, int x1, int y1, int z1)
    {
        int blocks = 0;
        bool cannotUndo = false;

        int dx = x1 - x0;
        int dy = y1 - y0;
        int dz = z1 - z0;

        DrawOneBlock (theplayer, drawBlock, x0, y0, z0, ref blocks, ref cannotUndo);
        if (Math.Abs(dx) > Math.Abs(dy))
        {          // slope < 1
            float m = (float)dy / (float)dx;      // compute slope
            float b = y0 - m * x0;
            dx = (dx < 0) ? -1 : 1;
            while (x0 != x1)
            {
                x0 += dx;
                DrawOneBlock(theplayer, drawBlock, x0, Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(m * x0 + b)), z0, ref blocks, ref cannotUndo);
            }
        }
        else
        {

            if (dy != 0)
            {                              // slope >= 1
                float m = (float)dx / (float)dy;      // compute slope
                float b = x0 - m * y0;
                dy = (dy < 0) ? -1 : 1;
                while (y0 != y1)
                {
                    y0 += dy;
                    DrawOneBlock(theplayer, drawBlock, Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(m * y0 + b)), y0, z0, ref blocks, ref cannotUndo);
                }
            }
        }
        return blocks;
    }
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
internal static int DrawLine(Player theplayer, Byte drawBlock, int x0, int y0, int z0, int x1, int y1, int z1)
    {
        int blocks = 0;
        bool cannotUndo = false;
        bool detected = false;

        int dx = x1 - x0;
        int dy = y1 - y0;
        int dz = z1 - z0;

        DrawOneBlock (theplayer, drawBlock, x0, y0, z0, ref blocks, ref cannotUndo);

    //a>x,b>y,c>z
    if (Math.Abs(dx) > Math.Abs(dy) && Math.Abs(dx) > Math.Abs(dz) && detected == false)
        { // x distance is largest
            detected = true;
            float my = (float)dy / (float)dx;      // compute y slope
            float mz = (float)dz / (float)dx;      // compute z slope
            float by = y0 - my * x0;
            float bz = z0 - mz * x0;
            dx = (dx < 0) ? -1 : 1;
            while (x0 != x1)
            {
                x0 += dx;
                DrawOneBlock(theplayer, drawBlock, Convert.ToInt32(x0), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(my * x0 + by)), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(mz * x0 + bz)), ref blocks, ref cannotUndo);
            }
        }

    //a>y,b>z,c>x
    if (Math.Abs(dy) > Math.Abs(dz) && Math.Abs(dy) > Math.Abs(dx) && detected == false && detected == false)
        { // y distance is largest
            detected = true;
            float mz = (float)dz / (float)dy;      // compute z slope
            float mx = (float)dx / (float)dy;      // compute x slope
            float bz = z0 - mz * y0;
            float bx = x0 - mx * y0;
            dy = (dy < 0) ? -1 : 1;
            while (y0 != y1)
            {
                y0 += dy;
                DrawOneBlock(theplayer, drawBlock, Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(mx * y0 + bx)), Convert.ToInt32(y0) , Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(mz * y0 + bz)), ref blocks, ref cannotUndo);
            }
        }

    //a>z,b>x,c>y
    if (Math.Abs(dz) > Math.Abs(dx) && Math.Abs(dz) > Math.Abs(dy) && detected == false && detected == false)
        { // z distance is largest
            detected = true;
            float mx = (float)dx / (float)dz;      // compute x slope
            float my = (float)dy / (float)dz;      // compute y slope
            float bx = x0 - mx * z0;
            float by = y0 - my * z0;
            dz = (dz < 0) ? -1 : 1;
            while (z0 != z1)
            {
                z0 += dz;
                DrawOneBlock(theplayer, drawBlock, Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(mx * z0 + bx)), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(my * z0 + by)), Convert.ToInt32(z0), ref blocks, ref cannotUndo);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean adding a z dimension so that you are filling in a 3D raster (voxel field) instead? Otherwise what does the height mean in your case, isn't y0 and y1 the height?

Comment: I did not explain it correctly. I can currently draw a line on a flat surface from x0,y0 to x1,y1 and the pixels inbetween are filled correctly to complete the line.

Comment: I then have to add a h0 component to get the height above this flat surface for depth to determine which layer it appears on similar scaled depth grids.

Comment: I would like a line that spans x,y and z dimensions in the end. The line will run from point x0,y0,z0 to point x1,y1,z1. I am no longer using pixels in the required outcome. I am treating it as a 20x20x20 cube and want to place a 3d line inside this cube. Sorry - I am not able to word this better.

Comment: The two points are on the same plane, z=0; Did you want to render this in a 3/4 or an isometric perspective?

Comment: I don't think I need any perspectives, just the x,y,z coords for each cell that will be marked between 2 points in a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to compare `abs(dx)`, `abs(dy)`, and `abs(dz)` and pick the biggest one.  In each case use code like to what you have, computing both other coordinates similarly:

```
if (Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy) && Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dz)) { // x distance is largest
    float my = (float) dy / (float) dx;      // compute y slope
    float mz = (float) dz / (float) dx;      // compute z slope
    float by = y0 - my*x0;
    float bz = z0 - mz*x0;
    dx = (dx < 0) ? -1 : 1;
    while (x0 != x1) {
        x0 += dx;
        raster.setPixel(pix, x0, Math.round(my*x0 + by), Math.round(mz*x0 + bz));
    }
```

Comment: I am unsure of if this is a replacement for the code I have or if this is meant to be inserted into part of the area. I believe you have pin pointed what I mean though. Can you provide me with any more information about implementing this?

Comment: My apologies not understanding, but I can't work out where to put this code. I didn't write the original code, it was given to me. So could you please explain it or replace it in my code if possible?

Comment: This was the code that made it possible, just had to duplicate, run 3 times to see which one was bigger (x,y or z). Also included Bool detected and if statements to support. The cleaner way to do this would have been "if else" statements.